# How do I use LINQ to .Select from a List inside a Map?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to .Select specific elements from a List that are being stored inside a Dictionary.

```
internal Dictionary<string, List<Teamkill>> teamkillCounter = new Dictionary<string, List<Teamkill>>();

class Teamkill
{
    public string killerName;
    public string killerSteamId;
    public TeamRole killerTeamRole;
    public string victimName;
    public string victimSteamId;
    public TeamRole victimTeamRole;
    public DamageType damageType;
}

// quotedArgs[1] is the killer name being searched for

// First attempt
List<Teamkill> teamkills = this.plugin.teamkillCounter.Select(x => x.Value.Select(y => y.killerName.Contains(quotedArgs[1])).Cast<List<Teamkill>>()).Cast<List<Teamkill>>().Single();

// Second attempt
List<Teamkill> teamkills = new List<Teamkill>();
teamkills = this.plugin.teamkillCounter.Values.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
teamkills = teamkills.Where(y => y.killerName.Contains(quotedArgs[1])).ToList();
```

Ideally it should return a list of all Teamkills that match the killer's name.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yeah ignore my minging. I'm just trying to get things done really quick today and I had to go back to the tab 3 times because the steps disrupted my flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand your desired results, you probably can just use [`Values`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=netframework-4.7.2), [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
var result = teamkillCounter.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Where(y => y.killerName.Contains("bobo")));
```

---

[`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Values` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets a collection containing the values in the
>   Dictionary.

[`Enumerable.SelectMany` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>` and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence.

Comment: I'll try it now!

Comment: I tested this last night and edited in the changes that made this work for me. Thank you very much for the help!